# transparencize a background image on Photoshop

Tags: image, photoshop, grayscale, gimp

I would like to use [this background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz7nK.png) on different pages of my website.

The idea is to have a different color, instead of being grey. I am trying to change the color on Photoshop, and found this topic: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/replace-black-background-with-a-transparent-background but the result is not the one I was expecting.

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to make something transparent? Or a different colour? And **what** is supposed to become transparent (or a different colour) exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be in Graphic Design rather than on Stack Overflow, unless you're looking for someway to do it with Photoshop scripting. 
If you're looking for simply changing the shade from gray to say orange or green.  I would select the layer then go to Image>Adjustments and play around with Hue/Saturation.  Play around with that.  There may be another way to do it but that's what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can change it with Photoshop.
Follow these easy steps:
1. Go to main navigation - Images -> Adjustments -> Hue/Saturation...
[image]

2. You must select "Colorize", then you can play with the Hue to find your color and with the saturation to saturate it.
   [image]

Enjoy! :)